# Cronbach Alpha system is computationally singular

Tags: r

I have a scale where I'm attempting to run Cronbach Alpha on to test its reliability. I have read a lot of research on it in relation to tau equivalence (All items should contribute equally to the construct)

I have written a small function in R which takes advantage of the `tau.test` in the `coefficientalpha` package.

However when I run it I get the following errors:

```
> Error in solve.default(A) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.82436e-18
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In pf(trf, df, n - df) : NaNs produced
2: In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
  lavaan WARNING: could not compute standard errors!
  lavaan NOTE: this may be a symptom that the model is not identified.
```

My question is can someone explain the errors to me and how to either remedy them or suggest an alternative method for seeing if the questions contribute equally to the construct. I suspect its that I don't have enough attributes.

A reproducible example is below:

```
x  <- round(rnorm(n=709 ,mean = 6, sd = 1))
x1 <-round(rnorm(n=709 ,mean = 5.6, sd = 1.3))

mydf <- data.frame(A1 = x,
               A2 = x1
)

mdl = coefficientalpha::bootstrap(as.data.frame(mydf), 
                              type='alpha', 
                              alpha=.95, 
                              nboot=100, 
                              ci="bc", 
                              plot=FALSE)

tau <- coefficientalpha::tau.test(as.data.frame(mydf))
```

Comment: This might be better suited to R-help or StackOverflow.

Comment: If you are interested in a statistical question about Cronbach's alpha you can submit a question here.  But it looks like it is only a technical question about implementation in R and should be migrated to the StackOverflow site as mdewey suggests.

Comment: This looks to be a problem with the coefficientalpha package, which isn't particularly well documented so it's not easy to see why it fails in this simple situation.  Compare psych::alpha(mydf), which does work whereas coefficientalpha::alpha(mydf) doesn't.  You might have to ask the authors.

Comment: BTW there's a bit of redundancy in your code; mydf is already a data.frame for instance so no need to wrap it in as.data.frame.  And for a simpler example, you could have skipped creating x and x1 as intermediate objects and just had A1 and A2 defined directly.

Comment: Thanks all. I will go down the `psych::alpha(mydf)` but it doesn't have a tau equivalence test as far as i can see which would have been really useful for my purposes.